# Determining a PDF from a situation alone

Tags: probability, statistics

How can one determine the probability function $f(x)$ given a situation and no equations? I am unsure if there is a special method or if you should just plug in values and look for a pattern.

For example, if you draw 2 numbers from 0 through 9 without replacement, and $X=$ {total of the 2 numbers}, then how could you determine $f(x)$? I came up with the sample space $|S|= {10 \choose 2}$, and found probabilities for X = 1,2,3, ... etc.

I got $\frac{1}{10 \choose 2}$ for $X=1$ and $X=2$ and then the numerator increases by 1 for $X=3,4$, increases again by one for 4 and 5, and then values are repeated in pairs like that if I have done this correctly. My confusion is how to determine a formula now. Can it even be done?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you just find the probability that your random variable can assume a particular value.

$X$ is the total of two numbers. So of course, $X\in\{1,2,...,17\}$.

Now $f_X(x)=P(X=x)$ where $x$ is one of these numbers, otherwise $f_X(x)=0$.

Now I believe you can compute $P(X=x)$ for each $x$ in the range of $X$, right?

Comment: They're asking for a closed-form solution.